# RETURN relationship details after FOREACH in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This Cypher Query for the following setup: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ys7iye

```
MATCH (U:User),(P:Product {name: "Apple"}) 
WITH COLLECT([U]) As Users, U, P 
FOREACH (User IN Users | 
CREATE (U)-[r:buys]->(P) 
SET r.amount = 123)
RETURN {Amount: r.amount}
```

returns

`` Variable `r` not defined ``

How can I return Details of `r` ?

*Edited question after comment of cybersam today*

Comment: 1. You have a typo; presumably your actual Cypher code has a `)` after the `123`. 2. Given your query, `U` and `P` should also not be defined (when you try to return them). Can you update your question to show your actual query and describe the actual behavior?

Comment: Also, `User` is not used at all in the `FOREACH`. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any variables defined within a `FOREACH` clause are not available outside of it.

As a workaround, you can just use `UNWIND` to avoid using `FOREACH`. For example, this form of your query should work:

```
...
UNWIND users as user
CREATE (U)-[r:buys]->(P) 
SET r.amount = 123
RETURN {Amount: r.amount}
```

*Note: The query does not actually use `user`, and would make multiple copies of the same nodes and relationships. I assume your question does not contain your real query.*

Comment: Great, that's it ... Here is the query in Neo4j console: http://console.neo4j.org/r/i80ro